# How to draw custome text inside polygon in KML?

Tags: kml

I want to draw custome text inside polygon using KML file.
My Kml file for Polygon-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Document><Style id="White"><PolyStyle><color>64FFFFFF</color></PolyStyle></Style><Placemark><styleUrl>#white</styleUrl><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-95.27999999999997,30.0175 -95.27166999999997,30.0175 -95.27166999999997,30.01083 -95.27999999999997,30.01083 -95.27999999999997,30.0175</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><ExtendedData><Data name="isColorful">true</Data><Data name="color">white</Data></ExtendedData></Placemark></Document></kml>
```

am i missing any tag or property to show text in the center of polygon.
Please help.

Actually , I want to show some data inside polygon, I created KML using  with Point and polygon.
-I made icon scale 0 to hide icon .
it shows name label inside polygon in "Google Earth", but it does not show label in "Google map".
Please see my sample KML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Document><Style id="White"><IconStyle> <color>ff00ff00</color>         <colorMode>random</colorMode><scale>0</scale></IconStyle><LabelStyle><scale>0.6</scale></LabelStyle><PolyStyle><color>64FFFFFF</color></PolyStyle></Style><Placemark><name>64,100</name><styleUrl>#White</styleUrl><MultiGeometry><Point><coordinates>-95.27899999999997,30.0172</coordinates></Point><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-95.27999999999997,30.0175 -95.27166999999997,30.0175 -95.27166999999997,30.01083 -95.27999999999997,30.01083 -95.27999999999997,30.0175</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry></Placemark><Placemark><name>65,93</name><styleUrl>#White</styleUrl><MultiGeometry><Point><coordinates>-95.27066999999997,29.97053</coordinates></Point><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-95.27166999999997,29.97083 -95.26333999999997,29.97083 -95.26333999999997,29.96417 -95.27166999999997,29.96417 -95.27166999999997,29.97083</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry></Placemark></Document></kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the elements in the KML are out of order making it invalid KML with respect to the KML 2.2 specification. The KML should first be validated. Some tips to validate KML are discussed [here](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlBestPractice.html#KML_Validation_Tools).

The ExtendedData element is incorrect. Missing required `value` element.

```
<ExtendedData>
    <Data name="isColorful">true</Data>
    <Data name="color">white</Data>
</ExtendedData>
```

This need to be restructued:

```
<ExtendedData>
    <Data name="isColorful">
        <value>true</value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="color">
        <value>white</value>
    </Data>
</ExtendedData>
```

If KML placemark has ExtendedData then these data fields are formatted in a human readable HTML table in the description balloon popup when clicked.

If you want to override the HTML table then add a `<description>` to your KML placemark which can contain HTML markup. See description section in [KML reference docs](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#feature).

UPDATE:
If want text to appear on the polygon then need to include Point and Polygon in MultiGeometry as you describe but also need a `<name>` element added to the Placemark. The text of the name element will be the label that is displayed at the position of the point. This works in Google Earth but not in Google Maps. KML has some limitations in Google Maps. If want to add text to center of your polygon, then add a label marker via Google Maps API.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels

Comment: Actually , I want to show some data inside polygon, I created KML using <MultiGeometry> with Point and polygon.
-I made icon scale 0 to hide icon .
it shows name label inside polygon in "Google Earth", but it does not show label in "Google map".